# Save Wordpress post in edit mode through a custom save button

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress provides default save post button. Now, I want to do some preprocessing on the content written in wordpress editor (which is not yet saved into database) and then save it in database (both the tasks in a single button click). I don't want to use wp_insert_post hook because I want to give the option of preprocessing on demand through a different button and then save the preprocessed post also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wp_insert_post_data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data) for changes data before save process

Comment: But, it will always do the pre-processing once saved. I want to do the pre-processing on demand and save the pre-processed content into database.